# How to download a FIle? Either Image or PDF

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-8

My backend controller for the download.

```
public function myAppointment($id)
{
    $appointment = Appointment::find($id);    
    return response()->json($appointment);
}
```

This is where I find a certain appointment via ID and gets it's details and would only select the image.

However, when I clicked on the download it shows that we don't support this format.

[image]

My frontend controller.

```
showPhoto(file) {
      const bearerToken = localStorage.getItem("Bearer");

      axios
        .get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/my-appointment/${file.id}`, {
          responseType: "blob", // important
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/pdf",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${bearerToken}`,
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]));
          const link = document.createElement("a");
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute("download", res.data.file);
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
          link.remove();
        });
    },
```

The parameters inside the showPhoto is that the data I get in the v-for.

How can I fix these things? what might be wrong in my code.

[image]

I even checked the database in xampp and it is getting the original name and when I check my backend public folder it is there.

How can I resolve this? Can anyone explain what is the problem and what is the solution in this.

This is my first time building an uploading of Photo, PDF, or even DOCX file and having a download in it.

Comment: What was the 500 error saying in your `laravel.log` file?

Comment: @Rooneyl i have updated my question. Can you see the problem?

Comment: That error when you click on the image suggests the file is wrong. As it is giving you a 500 error, I would expect to see an error in your log file (normally at `storage/logs/laravel.log`. What is the error in there?

Comment: Why does your axios call have `Accept: "application/pdf"` if you want to download an image? You should be able to just remove that line.

Comment: here's the Github repositories.

Comment: https://github.com/Michaelangelo-GrizzlyBear/Freelance.git